# Python setup.py interactive user prompt

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have a Python package with a Python and a native implementation of the same thing. Usually, both are installed, but sometimes only the Python implementation is wanted if the user doesn't have the required dependencies to compile the native code.

So I want to ask the user if they additionally want to install the native version (Y/N) and change what is installed accordingly. However, as soon as I use Python's `input('Install native? (Y/N)')` at the top of my `setup.py` script, I get `EOFError: EOF when reading a line`. `print`ing in the script also doesn't appear do do anything. I install the script with `pip install .`.

What can I do to get the desired result?

Comment: `setup.py` can't take user input.

Comment: I see. Any suggestions to work around that? Or do I need to offer two separate scripts?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463824/declaring-optional-components-of-my-package-in-setup-py

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful because it stated it's basically not possible. Instead, I used an environment variable to change the behavior depending on the state of the environment variable, or if it's present at all.